# Incorrect results when using a certain $u$-substitutions during circular integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

For example, $$\int \sin(2t)e^{t/2}dt = 2\sin(2t)e^{t/2}-4\int \cos(2t)e^{t/2}dt$$

if we make the substitution $u= sin(2t), dv = e^{t/2}dt $

Now I want to solve for $\int \cos(2t)e^{t/2}dt$ in the hope that $\int \sin(2t)e^{t/2}dt$ will appear again on the left hand side of the equation:

---

While solving $\int \cos(2t)e^{t/2}dt$, if I make the substitutions $u=\cos(2t), dv=e^{t/2}dt$, then I get the correct answer in the end.

However, if I make the substitutions $u = e^{t/2}, dv=\cos(2t) dt$, then I get:

$$\int \cos(2t)e^{t/2}dt  = \frac12 \sin(2t)e^{t/2} - \frac14 \int \sin(2t)e^{t/2}dt $$

and plugging this into $\int \sin(2t)e^{t/2}dt = 2\sin(2t)e^{t/2}-4\int \cos(2t)e^{t/2}dt$ gives us the useless equation of $\int \sin(2t)e^{t/2}dt = \int \sin(2t)e^{t/2}dt$.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going through hell, keep going. Or don't change horses in midstream. Or whichever proverb you prefer.

Reversing your substitution midway through will indeed undo your progress. However, if you persevere and make $dv=e^{t/2}dt$ again, you get
$$
\int \sin(2t) e^{t/2}\,dt = 2e^{t/2}\sin(2t)-4\int \cos(2t)e^{t/2}\,dt
$$
$$
\int \sin(2t) e^{t/2}\,dt = 2e^{t/2}\sin(2t)-4\left(2e^{t/2}\cos(2t)+4\int \sin(2t)e^{t/2}\,dt\right)
$$
$$
17\int \sin(2t) e^{t/2}\,dt = 2e^{t/2}\sin(2t)-8e^{t/2}\cos(2t)
$$
$$
\int \sin(2t) e^{t/2}\,dt= \frac{2e^{t/2}\sin(2t)-8e^{t/2}\cos(2t)}{17}+ C 
$$

Comment: Ah okay, so I have to similar substitutions twice in a row instead of switching around at the second integral. Thank you! Do you know why this is?

Comment: What's concerning is that in more complicated circular integration examples, the $u$, $du$, $v$, $dv$ of the first integral and the second integral may be too different for you to be able to tell which substitution on the second integral will undo your progress...

Comment: If you use IBP and get $\int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du$, if you then put $dv=du$, $u=v$, you'll get $uv-uv -(-\int u\,dv)$, which of course is back where you started. It's rare you need to do IBP more than a few times (unless the integral has a clear form, something like $\int x^{10}e^{x}\,dx$, where you do IBP ten times with $dv=e^x\,dx$ in each instance).